# Attempted to update to Natty Narhwal (11.04 alpha 3), Power was interrupted

Tags: upgrade, xorg, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-11.04

I set up my computer to run the update overnight; my grandmother said it was making a lot of noise so she shut it off.

Trouble is, the upgrade didn't finish. Now, Xorg refuses to start; the computer boots to command line, and 'startx' returns that the X Window Server has encountered a segfault. I'll be able to post outputs from whatever later, but right now I'm not at home.

Also, would investing in biometrics for the computer room be worth it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a boot disk to save your home folder and configs if you'd like, then reload from scratch. It's not worth your time to try and fix it.

If you're absolutely determined to fix it, you can try uninstalling/reinstalling xorg, and move on from there.

Also, skip the biometrics and find a nursing home for Granny.

Comment: Figured out what the problem is; the fglrx driver doesn't like the 64-bit version. Started using the radeon module instead.

Comment: Guess it wasn't interrupted during install, then!